# flutter firestore TextFormField Fixed Data value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my Flutter app I need to When the user enters data, I want that data to be fixed and appear on TextFormField like this   [image]

until the user enters a new data. How can I do this?

This is my TextFormField codes

```
           Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,0,15,0),


                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val){
                            return val.isEmpty || val.length > 4 ? "Geçerli Bir Kilo Giriniz": null;
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),

                          controller: weightTextEditingController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(

                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            labelText: "word",
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color:Colors.orange[900]
                            ),
                          ),

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: It's not clear is it you want to have a default value or just a hint for user

Comment: no its not hint. I want to set the data the user entered in the previous time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just intialize the field's contoller with your value:

```
var weightTextEditingController = TextEditingController(text: 'currentData');
```